# How to detect environment during deserialization

Tags: protobuf-net.grpc

Is there a way how to find out, If the constructor is called during deserialization on client or during deserialization on server? I talk about constructor of class marked with DataContract atribute from Shared project.

Thank you Tom

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("propertyName"). PropertyName should be placed in launchSettings.json for client and server.